# How do I destroy a session by clicking a button?

Tags: php, forms, session, logout, destroy

This should be an easy one, if I explain it well.

I am trying to create a web page, where the session starts when the user enters a name, the name is displayed constantly, until the user presses the log out button; which should end the session. The closest I have gotten to is this:

```
<if (isset($_POST['name'])) {

    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST["name"];

    echo "<input type='submit' name='logout' method='logout' value='Log out'>";
                echo "</form>";
            echo "</h1>";
                            echo "</div>";

    if(isset($_POST['logout']) && ($_POST['logout'] == "Log out")) { 
    session_destroy(); }
```

but it doesn't end the session and the name keeps being displayed constantly once entered. i.e. There is no way to end the session.

If you need any more explanation, or more of the code to understand, please let me know. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: i don't think it's needed to check $_POST['logout'] value, but try with `unset($_SESSION);`

Comment: try getting rid of the "&& ($_POST['logout'] == "Log out")".

Comment: Did you make sure that the code inside the `if` is actually reached?

Comment: `method='logout'` what's that? <= Being invalid; methods don't belong in elements, but in `<form>` only. Where are your form tags anyway?

Comment: I noticed you missed an indent, which contained `<if (isset($_POST['name'])) {` remove the `<` that shouldn't be in there. You need to show your full code.

Comment: You also need to include `session_start();` - Very hard to give a definite answer, if that is only part of your code and not full code.

Answer (score 1):

You can change `session_destroy()` by `unset($_SESSION['name'])` , like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {

    $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST["name"];

    echo "<input type='submit' name='logout' method='logout' value='Log out'>";
    echo "</form>";
    echo "</h1>";
    echo "</div>";

    if(isset($_POST['logout']) && ($_POST['logout'] == "Log out")) { 
        unset($_SESSION['name']); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `session_unset()` to destroy all registered variables in the session and if you want unset a specific variable like `name` use `unset($_SESSION['name'])`

Do NOT unset the whole $_SESSION with `unset($_SESSION)` as this will disable the registering of session variables through the $_SESSION superglobal.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a call to session_commit() just after session_destroy();

Answer (score 0):

The code below handles the Logout hyperlink, so it creates the global variable logout and it unsets the session

```
    <a href="?logout">Log out</a>
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    session_unset();
    }
    ?>
```